# Telnet server on linux redhat - deletes char, shifts on terminal console

Tags: linux, redhat, telnet, console-server

When I open telnet client from local or remote console, I get damaged output in console like below example:
-welcome screen appears properly  (also when I put some text into nss.
-1st char of words ( localhost, password ,last login... ) is deleted
-every line if shifted right
-hidden are all my inputs from keyboard

Service works normally login success, but I am unable to control it by keyboard. I tested previous compiled versions of telnet-server no success.

Does anybody have some tip?

```
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
Kernel 3.6.10-4.fc18.i686.PAE on an i686 (2)
ocalhost login:
       assword:
          ast login: Wed Mar 20 07:12:32 from 172.24.4.237
]0;efx@localhost:~[?1034hefx@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Why are you using telnet?! Try again with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

The best tip, as Michael Hampton says is **do not use telnet**

> I open telnet client from local or remote console

Are you telneting to the local machine? Or does this happen when you telnet off the server and in? Top of my list to check would be that your TERM setting is correct and the termcap database is present / not corrupted.